# Using onDelete with alertDialog

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a widget that deletes an item.

This is what I am currently using, and it's working perfectly.

```
 Expanded(
                            child: ElevatedButton.icon(
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.delete,
                          ),
                          label: Text('Delete'),
                          onPressed: onDelete,
                        )),
```

The code below doesn't work.

```
 Expanded(
                            child: ElevatedButton.icon(
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.delete,
                          ),
                          label: Text('Delete'),
                          onPressed: () => alert(context, onDelete),
                        )),
```

The alert looks something like this

```
alert(BuildContext context, onDelete) {
  Widget yesButton = TextButton(
    child: Text("Yes"),
    onPressed: () {
      debugPrint('clicked'); //working, It prints!
      onDelete; //this is not working
      Navigator.pop(context);
    },
  );

  // set up the AlertDialog
  AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
    title: Text("Do you want to delete?"),
    content: Text("Are you sure you want to delete this item?"),
    actions: [
      yesButton,
    ],
  );

  // show the dialog
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return alert;
    },
  );
}
```

Since my initial code is working, some users missclick and delete the item. I would like to add an alert, but can't figure it out how to do it so, since the onDelete is not working inside the onpressed function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to aux4!

```
void alert(BuildContext context, void Function() onDelete) {}
```

and

```
onDelete; //this is not working
onDelete(); // this should work a bit better
```